# Symfony2 demo extension is not enabled

Tags: php, symfony

I'm starting on learning symfony2, and downloaded the symfony with vendors. But I'm not getting run symfony on the production environment, he returns the following error:

> request.CRITICAL: Twig_Error_Runtime: The "demo" extension is not enabled in "AcmeDemoBundle: Demo: hello.html.twig" at line 9

I've tried setting the config.yml like this:

```
services:
     twig.extension.acme.demo:
         class: Acme\DemoBundle\Twig\Extension\DemoExtension
         tags:
             - {Name: twig.extension}
         arguments:
             - @ Twig.loader
```

I've tried to add also the bundle Acme in autoload.php, but still did not work ... still gives the same error.

The only way to make it work is to set debug to true on this line:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel ('prod', false);
```

but I do not want to do this in a production environment because it would not be good.

Could anyone help me please?

Ps.: Sorry for my english

**Edit:**

In the view has a code like this: {% set code = code(_self) %}

If i change the part code(_self) to something else, it work perfectly...

But, why not run with that code?

Comment: Why is there a space between `@` and `Twig.loader` ?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably having this issue because you're accessing the prod version where the `AcmeDemoBundle` is only loaded in the development environment.

Make sure that you're accessing `app_dev.php` (development environment) instead of using the `.htaccess` or `app.php` (production environment) methods.

**Note:** I'm assuming that the code that you're playing with is not production code. If it is, you should create the twig extension in your own bundle that is loaded in all environments.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with the syntax :

```
services:
  twig.extension.acme.demo:
    class: Acme\DemoBundle\Twig\Extension\DemoExtension
    arguments:
         - @twig.loader
    tags:
         - { name: twig.extension }
```